# Date & Time picker in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I thought this was going to be easy given that I already had a date picker. But now I need a date and time picker on click of text box.

Does anyone have any solutions that they would like to share?

<kbd>NOTE</kbd>: `DATE + TIME` picker, not just date or time. I already have those two in separate text boxes.

Thanks for our help.

Comment: Having separate date & time inputs sounds like a better idea to me,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery DatePicker with Time extension. http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: Just got around to complete the testing today. Thank Colin Raaijmakers, there are some awesome datetimepicker there.

Comment: Colin Raaijmakers a big thank you. This is working perfectly for multiple textboxes!